# How can I add a reference to a List

Tags: c#, list, reference

I thought that a List holds references of objects, so I thought I could create an object of my own custom class called "Node", add it to a list and then later delete the object by assigning it with null. (I know I could use remove from the list, but that's not what I want to do.) So when I print the list again, it still prints with the name of the object "testNode" even though I assigned it with null. What can I do to add a reference to a list?

```
Node testNode = new Node("Name", id);
List<Node> listNodes = new List<Node>();
listNodes.Add(testNode);

for (int i = 0; i < listNodes.Count; i++)
    listNodes[i].ToString();

testNode = null;

for (int i = 0; i < listNodes.Count; i++)
    listNodes[i].ToString();
```

Comment: To answer the question in the title, you already are. testNode is **also** a reference so you've just set the testNode **reference** to null. The actual object is still there and it's being pointed at by the other reference (your list) so it remains unchanged

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you add to the list is *a reference to that instance of `Node`*. Not a referernce to your variable.

With

```
testNode = null;
```

you only assign `null` to your variable. This does nothing to the real instance `testNode` was referencing. And it does not change the list or remove the *reference* from the list.

So the only way to *remove* the reference from the list is - well - `Remove`:

```
listNodes.Remove(testNode);
```

Comment: Thank you! I achieved the thing I wanted to do by changing the member variables of the Node. So when I wrote `testNode.type = null;` it did change in the second print of the list.